# Finding the epoch for which the best accuracy happens in PyTorch after training a model in test mode

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to understand which epoch from a best saved model gives me the best accuracy.

Here's the code that is used:

```
best_acc = 0
# optionally resume from a checkpoint
if args.resume:
    if os.path.isfile(args.resume):
        print("=> loading checkpoint '{}'".format(args.resume))
        checkpoint = torch.load(args.resume)
        args.start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
        print(" start epoch: ", args.start_epoch)
        best_acc = checkpoint['best_prec1']
        print("best acc:" , best_acc)
        model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
        print("=> loaded checkpoint '{}' (epoch {})"
                .format(args.resume, checkpoint['epoch']))
    else:
        print("=> no checkpoint found at '{}'".format(args.resume))
```

I get this:

```
=> loading checkpoint 'runs/both_attn_30e_CA/model_best.pth.tar'
 start epoch:  6
best acc: 1.4967916199999998
=> loaded checkpoint 'runs/both_attn_30e_CA/model_best.pth.tar' (epoch 6)
```

I am running the code in test mode after training it for 30 epochs:

```
$ python main.py --test --use_fc --resume runs/both_attn_30e_CA/model_best.pth.tar
```

It prints 6 as the epoch of loaded checkpoint which is also start_epoch.
Essentially, I want to know which epoch gives me the best accuracy so if 10 epochs is enough, I won't train it for 30 epochs or rather if with 10 epochs, it is not converged I go ahead and train for more epochs.

I tried searching for `"checkpoint['best_prec1']"[1]` in Google but there was only two pages none a tutorial to exactly describe how to achieve the epoch for which this best_prec1 is obtained.

Trained model is saved in `runs/both_attn_30e_CA/model_best.pth.tar`

Comment: Are you fine-tuning a pre-trained model?

Comment: Are you looking for early stopping strategies?

Comment: I am training a custom resnet18 (modified resnet18) from scratch. stackoverflowuser2010

Comment: Downvoters aren't notified by anything. Again: are you looking for early stopping strategies?

Comment: in this specific question no. I just want to know which epoch of a trained model had the best accuracy. @Berriel

Comment: Are you creating the `checkpoint` dict yourself, when saving the model before resuming? If so there might be an issue in how you do that (the code for that is not in your post).

Comment: @GoodDeeds yes the checkpoint which is pth.tar is a model trained by me.